# How to remove the button color created for setselected property in ios

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a button. When I am selecting it it's background color changes to blue. As inside the code I have made `setSelected = Yes`. I am to remove this color. I have also tried

`button.tintcolor=[uicolor clearcolor];`

Also I have tried

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];

[self.selectAllButton setTintColor:color];
```

But by doing these two methods the `tintcolor` is cleared but the button text also disappeared.

How to remove this button `tintcolor` without affecting the button `text color`.

Comment: Your text color is same as your button's tint color?

Comment: Yes.Text color is same as button's tint color.

Comment: That is why your text color is not visible

Comment: Then how to fix this issue? Can you please help me.

Comment: You need to either change your tint color or text color. Both of the colors are same that is why they are not visible

Comment: Thanks.... I have changed the tint color. But still sometimes the text of the button is not showing .

Comment: Set title color like this : button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal) //use whatever color

Comment: Could you please specify exact what you want?